# How can a package maintainer prevent file collisions with Ubuntu packages, like trying to overwrite 'file', which is also in package?

Tags: package-management

I develop (or maintain) a package, I've gotten several bug reports along the lines of:

```
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libjline-java_1.0-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/java/jline.jar', which is also in package scala 2.9.2-400
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libjline-java_1.0-1_all.deb
```

but I haven't found a way to prevent/find them before someone hits them. How can I prevent these file conflicts/collisions before this even happens?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To prevent this with Ubuntu packages you can use `apt-file` and just run all your package against the file database that can be found using apt-file:

```
apt-file search -D your_deb_file.deb
```

This will require that you have `apt-file` installed and updated. Then add the package name (and possibly version) to the `Break` or `Conflict` fields, in the respective package entries in the control file. That should be enough.

Now, some would want to replace Ubuntu files with their own, like offering a newer version of the applications, in such cases the best is to use the same `debian/` files as the Ubuntu packages. This will create your package with the same shape as upstream and file collisions can be adverted.

Note: if the user likes to mix repositories from different maintainers, nothing you can do.